# When designing classes, how do you deal with sub-types?

Tags: oop, architecture

I'm learning about object oriented design as I go through my first real, albeit personal, project.

I'm at the stage where I'm going to build a user object. I have 4 user subtypes:

1. root-admin - webmaster, site owner
2. group-admin - leader of a group that has a membership and page (e.g. band manager)
3. group-member - user that can view, post, and comment as group member on the page and see private content (e.g. band member)
4. unassociated user - member of the entire site that can view and comment publicly (e.g. fan)

All group admins will be group members and all group members will be unassociated users as well. So basically it's a simple user permissions hierarchy.

With that said, how do I go about setting up the architecture of my class with respect to these levels? Is there a nesting technique? I'm just struggling to hash out the scaffolding here. I have my use cases and narratives written out already.

Comment: You should consider using composition instead of sub-typing/inheritance in this case.

Comment: I was reading about composition and found out that PHP only accepts one parent. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I misunderstood what I was reading. It's getting too complex for me. For my purposes, this may work. But I'm reading an article about why composition is bad, and I think I'm getting into complex methodology that on not ready for lol... I want to learn it right, from the start, but I'm getting in over my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're implementing role-based access control. Each user has one of four roles. So a user is an object and the users's role is one of the attributes in a user object.

```
enum roles {
   root_admin,
   group_admin,
   group_member,
   unassociated_user
}

class user {
   string id;
   roles role;
}
```

Next, you need to enforce the business rules that allow users of certain roles to do certain activities.

Start with a simple solution (this is always a good policy):

```
enum activities {
   view,
   post,
   add_comment
}
```

And implement a function or class whose job is to say if an activity is allowed for a given role.

```
class role_based_access_control {
private:
      permissions perm;
public:
   bool is_permitted(activities a, roles r) {
      return perm[r].contain(a);
   }
}
```

Then, in places in your code where you implement different activities, include a call to this function:

```
void add_comment_to_page(user u, comment c, page p) {
   if (!role_base_access_control.is_permitted(add_comment,u.role))
      throw "access_forbidden";
   ... 
}
```

The important thing is to keep the role based access control rules centralized so that they are visible, easy to monitor, and to audit.

Comment: This was beautifully simple. Thanks so much for taking the time to write this out. I was able to implement this in practice in seconds, and it brought me a better understanding of the process. Question, are there any security concerns with this method?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. There are always security concerns, but security reviews will typically be concerned with the other layers of the system which are beyond the scope of this discussion, such as how a user is authenticated, whether communication is encrypted, who has access to which servers. In any case, it's good to learn about the advantages and disadvantages of RBAC in general. You can contrast it with ABAC (see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37276/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-attribute-based-access-control).

Comment: I should probably iterate that I'm writing in PHP, and the answer here is given in reference to C. I had originally tagged this with PHP, but because I was easily able to transpose it, I didn't think about the disconnection until the tag was removed. There is no Emum declaration in PHP, and I had to write a small basic enumeration class to extend. If you have the ability to add extensions, you can use SPLenum. Anyway, this architecture is applicable across any language, but implementation might require some workarounds, as in my case.